# Google Spreadsheets API v4 - batchUpdate URL is incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

The Google Spreadsheets API v4 documentation appears to have an incorrect URL listed for batchUpdate.

The documentation lists:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchUpdate
```

however the following code

```
let range = "Sheet1!A\(index):\(index)"
let url = String(format:"%@/%@/values:batchUpdate/%@", baseUrl, spreadsheetId, range)
let params = ["valueInputOption":"RAW"]
let fullUrl = GTLUtilities.URLWithString(url, queryParameters: params)

let body = GTLObject()
body.JSON = ["majorDimension":"ROWS",
            "values": [values]]

driveService.fetchObjectByUpdatingObject(body, forURL: fullUrl, completionHandler: {
    (ticket:GTLServiceTicket!, object:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) in
```

results in

```
 <p>The requested URL <code>/v4/spreadsheets/....values:batchUpdate/Sheet1!A4:4?valueInputOption=RAW</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

What is the correct URL to use in this instance?

Comment: ...but what's your question?

Comment: The question is clear - what is the correct URL to use in this instance?

Comment: did you resolve this issue? am facing the same issue with batch update

Answer (score -1):

Your URL is incorrect.  The documentation states: `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchUpdate`

... but the URL you're using is: `POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/:batchUpdate/{range}?{parameters}`

In the batchUpdate method, the range is part of the body of the POST, one range for each update you're supplying.  See the https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/writing#write_to_multiple_ranges sample for details.

The code-sample you're using above seems to be for the normal update method, not the batchUpdate one.  See the other samples at the above link for more information.